# Bash Script elif Not Triggering

Tags: bash, scripting

I could use some help figuring out why the elif in the following script is not working. The first part of the if works, and the else part of the statement works, but the elif does not.  In other words, when I login as 'root' I get the DNS address I am expecting.  And if I log in as Guest, I get the DNS address I was expecting, but not if I login as any of the students listed in the elif.

```
#!/bin/bash

\# Setting DNS by User

\# Get variables. $3 is logging in user.
user=$3

\# Root and Admin should be wide open

if [ $user = "root" ] || [ $user = "admin" ]; then
networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi 8.8.8.8
networksetup -setdnsservers Ethernet 8.8.8.8

\# Older students get an open, but filtered experience:

elif 

\# Adams class
[ $user = "Student01" ] || 
[ $user = "Student02" ] || 
[ $user = "Student03" ] ||
[ $user = "Student04" ] ||

\# Mariannes class:
[ $user = "Student05" ] ||
[ $user = "Student06" ] ||
[ $user = "Student07" ] ||
[ $user = "Student08" ]   

then
networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi 8.8.4.4
networksetup -setdnsservers Ethernet 8.8.4.4

\# Everyone else gets whitelisted DNS

else
networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi 208.67.222.222
networksetup -setdnsservers Ethernet 208.67.222.222

fi

exit 0
```

Comment: Why do you prepend all `#` with backslash?

Comment: Only because I found a sample script online to start from and the comments were that way.  Is that not customary?

Comment: It should give you a runtime error `#: command not found`.

Comment: How are you actually running the script?

Comment: What *do* you get if you log in as one of the named students? (If you aren't getting `8.8.4.4`, presumably you are getting the whitelisted DNS servers, but I'm hesitant to assume anything about what you are actually running at the moment.)

Comment: It is being run as root by a jamf framework whenever someone logs in. I was getting the 'else' dns server for anyone other than admin and root. However, I have corrected the comments to only use # (as opposed to \#) and now the script seems to be working as expected!

Comment: You should surround your variable with double quotes, like this : "$user", and pls remove those uggly backslashes as 1st char.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is this is not really a maintainable approach. This is (in
my opinion) not the way to use the if / elif / if / fi structure.

That said, I have going to throw some advanced script at you that will do what
you want and is far more supportable.

First, I recommend keeping admin and student names in bash arrays. Eventually,
you can populate those arrays from another source (such as a file: shown in
comments). This will make the if / elif tests much simpler as shown.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# Setting DNS by User

# Get variables. $3 is logging in user.
user=$3

# admin_list=$HOME/admin.list
# declare -a admins
# if [[ -f "$admin_list" ]] ; then
#     IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a admins < <(sed -e 's/#.*$//' "$admin_list")
# 
#     wait $! || return $?
# else
#     echo "$admin_list not found: skipping"
# fi

declare -a admins=( root admin )

# special_list=$HOME/special.list
# declare -a special
# if [[ -f "$special_list" ]] ; then
#     IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a special < <(sed -e 's/#.*$//' "$special_list")
# 
#     wait $! || return $?
# else
#     echo "$special_list not found: skipping"
# fi

declare -a special=(

# Adams class
"Student01"
"Student02"
"Student03"
"Student04"

# Mariannes class:
"Student05"
"Student06"
"Student07"
"Student08"

)

# Root and Admin should be wide open

if [[ " ${admins[@]} " =~ " $user " ]] ; then

    echo Admin

    # networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi 8.8.8.8
    # networksetup -setdnsservers Ethernet 8.8.8.8

elif [[ " ${special[@]} " =~ " $user " ]] ; then

    # Older students get an open, but filtered experience:
    # Adams class

    echo Special

    # networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi 8.8.4.4
    # networksetup -setdnsservers Ethernet 8.8.4.4

else

    echo "Everyone else"
    # Everyone else gets whitelisted DNS

    # networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi 208.67.222.222
    # networksetup -setdnsservers Ethernet 208.67.222.222

fi

exit 0
```

Note: I commented out the nerworksetup from your script and added an echo
for each condition for testing. You can remove the echo lines and uncomment the
networksetup lines.

I tested it as:

```
$ script a1 a2 root
Admin

$ script a1 a2 Student02
Special

$ script a1 a2 Student1000
Everyone else
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Nice, with the use office areas :-)

Comment: Sorry, you lost me on office areas

Comment: A simple `case` statement would be perfectly portable and a lot less hoopla.

Comment: Sure a case statement would work at this level. However, if the number of students begins to increase, a case statement is not scale well. That is where using external lists is useful.

Comment: I am also guilty of over thinking an issue sometimes :)

Comment: `=~` isn't really a replacement for an `in` operator; it can trigger false matches if you are looking for `me too` in an array containing `home` and `tool`. If you want to simulate a containment operator, use an associative array where you can check if a given string is a key in the array.

Comment: `case " $user " in ;
" ${admins[@]} ") : ... ;;
esac;`

Comment: chepner - I completely agree that =~ is not a replacement for an in operator.  That was not my intention. By surrounding the user variable and array elements with spaces as in '" $user " =~ " $admins[@] "' mismatches are eliminated. If do have an example where this would does show a mismatch I would love to see it. I have been using this method for years in a number of scripts and if it can be made to show false matches, I will need to address this myself.

Comment: Paull Hodges - Unfortunately, " ${admins[@]} ") will expand to " root " " admin
") which will fail to match.

Comment: chepner - sorry I meant " $user " =~ " ${admins[@]} "'